# 2 variable Functional Equations

Tags: functions

Suppose a function $f : R->R$ satisfies the following conditions

1. $f(4xy) = 2y[f(x+y)+f(x-y)]$
2. $f(5)=3$

What is the value of $f(2015)$?

I am currently stuck after $x=y$ which gives out:

$f(4y^2) = 2y(f(2y))$

After getting this, I notice that

$4y^2 = (2y)^2$. So maybe the function also has this property

$f(xy) = xf(y)$. So maybe $403 \cdot 3 = 1209$ is the answer? It is not proven though. I need help with what to substitute in to the functional equation. Thanks

Comment: "Functional Analysis" is something else.

Comment: My mistake, it was called functional equations, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the function $f(x) = \frac{3}{5}x$, you can see that

1. $2y(f(x+y) + f(x-y)) = 2y(\frac{3}{5}(x+y) + \frac{3}{5}(x-y)) = \frac{3}{5}(2y((x + y) + (x - y))) = \frac{3}{5}(2y \cdot 2x) = f(4xy)$
2. $f(5) = \frac{3}{5} \cdot 5 = 3$

For this function, $f(2015) = 1209$ indeed.

It remains to show that this is the only function that satisfies the above conditions.
It is easy to show that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(-x) = -f(x)$. For the latter, just set $x = 0$ in the first condition. So maybe that's a help.